# AVPlayer vs. AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, audio, streaming, ios4, core-audio

The [documentation for AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer) states the following:

> [The] player works equally well with local and remote media files

However, the [documentation for AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudioplayer) states the following:

> Apple recommends that you use this class for audio playback unless you are playing audio captured from a network stream

For the work I am doing I need some of the capabilities of AVAudioPlayer, but all my audio is being streamed. The main thing I need from AVAudioPlayer that AVPlayer does not have is the "playing" property. It is difficult to build a player UI without that property, among others.

So what is the difference between AVPlayer and AVAudioPlayer that makes the latter unsuitable for network streaming? Is there a way to get some of the info from AVPlayer that AVAudioPlayer provides such as the "playing" property?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

1. AVPlayer can play from AVPlayerItem using AVURLAsset with an iPod library url. The AVAudioPlayer cannot play from an iPod library url.
2. AVPlayer has no volume property and requires the use of the system volume setting which can be controlled only by the hardware switch or an MPVolumeView. But you can set the mix volume of AVAudioPlayer.
3. AVPlayer seems to report an incorrect currentTime after seeking. But AVAudioPlayer reports accurately.

Comment: If you need exact timing for AVPlayer create AVURLAssets and pass the option ```AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey``` when you initialize it. Huzzah!

Comment: Is this still accurate? Have any important changes emerged in the past 3 years? Thanks

Comment: Wrong. For me, AVPlayer worked out perfect in performance, accuracy for getting current time. AVPlayer is great when you have to deal with graphical played time path. it is not running stupid NSTimer, but runs more smooth in GCD Block. Check the sample of - (id)addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:(CMTime)interval queue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue usingBlock:(void (^)(CMTime time))block; it just works great.

Comment: @mkc842, AVAudioPlayer can play from an iPod library URL since iOS 6. Also, you can set the volume of AVPlayer with the code at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6178912/462162

Answer (score 41):

7 years after...

From a point of view with dependence on Swift and CocoaPods, so my answer is comparing for **iOS 8+** only.

#### 1. iPod library support

[identical support since iOS6](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011812-SW1)

#### 2. volume control

identical support:

- You can set the mix volume of `AVAudioPlayer` directly.
- [You can set the mix volume of `AVPlayer` with an `AVAudioMix` on the `AVPlayerItem`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178912/1033581)

#### 3. seeking control

both AVPlayer and AVAudioPlayer seem to report an incorrect currentTime after seeking:

- for AVAudioPlayer, [it is suggested to `stop()` the `AVAudioPlayer` before seeking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882753/avaudioplayer-currenttime-issue)
- for AVPlayer, it is suggested to pass the option `AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey` when initializing AVURLAssets. [And rely on values given by observer block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588482/addperiodictimeobserverforinterval-called-extra-time).

#### 4. changing source

- you need only one `AVPlayer` to play multiple files
- you need multiple `AVAudioPlayer` to play multiple files

Comment: I would add that completion and error handling for AVPlayer is messed up (notification center, kvo, not really reporting errors at all when local path is wrong etc). AVAudioPlayer has do-catch for errors and a completion handler.

Answer (score 9):

The AVPlayer actually has a similar property as the playing property of AVAudioPlayer.
Take a look at the `rate` property.

Comment: Yeah I am using that now but it isn't super convenient. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: Hi Macinjosh,

If you figure out the exactly the difference between the two, please post it.