# addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval called extra time

Tags: ios, avplayer

I have a AVPlayer with 4 sec video (`NSTimeInterval duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.playerItem.asset.duration)` = 4).

I'd like to update UI with changes:

```
self.periodicTimeObserver = [self.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(1, 1) queue:dispatch_get_main_queue() usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {

    [weakSelf currentTimeDidChange:CMTimeGetSeconds(time)];

}];
```

But for some reasons I get extra calls to UI:

```
- (void)currentTimeDidChange:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
    NSLog(@"timePassed %f, total: %f", currentTime, self.duration);
}
```

Logs:

```
2015-07-23 13:47:07.412   timePassed 0.000000, total: 4.000000
2015-07-23 13:47:07.448   timePassed 0.002814, total: 4.000000
2015-07-23 13:47:07.450   timePassed 0.005481, total: 4.000000
2015-07-23 13:47:08.447   timePassed 1.001473, total: 4.000000
2015-07-23 13:47:09.446   timePassed 2.001612, total: 4.000000
2015-07-23 13:47:10.446   timePassed 3.002021, total: 4.000000
2015-07-23 13:47:11.446   timePassed 4.002139, total: 4.000000
2015-07-23 13:47:12.445   timePassed 5.001977, total: 4.000000
2015-07-23 13:47:12.492   timePassed 5.046618, total: 4.000000
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5):

you need to be sure that you are not calling periodicTimeObserver many time so do this write this code

```
if (self.periodicTimeObserver == nil){
self.periodicTimeObserver = [self.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(1, 1) queue:dispatch_get_main_queue() usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {

    [weakSelf currentTimeDidChange:CMTimeGetSeconds(time)];

}];
}
```

then as soon as your video is finishes playing remove observer

```
[player removeTimeObserver:self.periodicTimeObserver];
self.periodicTimeObserver = nil;
```

Comment: There should be a radar for this, since the API name `add` implied multiple observers support

Answer (score 1):

I got inconsistencies too. So I'm not relying on the value given by the block but on the value from the playerItem itself:

```
self.periodicTimeObserver = [self.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(1, 1) queue:nil usingBlock:^(__unused CMTime time) {
    [weakSelf currentTimeDidChange:CMTimeGetSeconds(self.playerItem.currentTime)];
}];
```