# The Operation Couldn’t Be Completed. (OSStatus Error 2003334207.)

Tags: ios, swift, audio, swiftui, avaudioplayer

I know this is a duplicate question but I did not find any solution that works for me.

I am using **AVAudioPlayer** to play an audio with the **url** which I am getting from **Firebase**. The **url** I get from **Firebase** is:

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/unified-45b5c.appspot.com/o/AudioMessage%2F5%2B8_5_Audio_07-09-20224:07:30.m4a?alt=media&token=af3aabce-46bd-4d55-a7ca-30623eaf1817

if I open this **url on google chrome** it gives me my audio. But when I try it using **AVAudioPlayer** it gives me the following error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

This is what I am doing:

```
Button {  
 
         vm.startPlaying(url: audioURL ?? URL(fileURLWithPath: "")) 
        } label: {

            Image(systemName: startAudio ? "pause.fill" : "play.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding()
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(width: 100)
                )
        }
```

And the function **startPlaying()**:

```
    func startPlaying(url : URL) {
                    
           do {
               audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf : url)
               audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
               audioPlayer.play()
                   
           } catch {
               Helper.shared.printDebug("Playing Failed")
               Helper.shared.printDebug(error.localizedDescription)  // error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)
           }
                   
       }
```

Comment: Often pure `error`s reveal more than their `localizedDescription`.

Comment: @vadian I am printing the error and it gives me this: "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)"

Comment: That's an *unspecified error* https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=2003334207. Is the `URL` valid? The browser is more tolerant than the `Foundation` framework. Better handle **that** error rather than passing completely pointless `URL(fileURLWithPath: "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initializer you are using for AVAudioPlayer expect an URL to a **local** file. You can’t pass it a URL to a file on a remote server. To quote the docs:

```
Declaration
init(contentsOf url: URL) throws
Parameters
url
A URL that identifies the local audio file to play
```

You’ll need to download the data to a local file before playing it, or use a method that supports streaming audio playback.

Answer (score 1):

Duncan's solution works if you want to download the item first, and then play it. If you want more like a streaming experience, you can use [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer), which is built to allow playing remote files, and helps with streaming:

> Use an instance of AVPlayer to play local and remote file-based media, such as QuickTime movies and MP3 audio files, as well as audiovisual media served using HTTP Live Streaming.

```
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item) 
let audio = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
player.play()
```

Note that you can keep an instance of the player to play multiple items

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42829233/5318223) for detailed comparison between the two

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer describing AVPlayer. (Voted.) I didn’t remember the class that handled streaming audio, and didn’t have time this morning to hunt for it.