# Set UISlider.value to AVPlayer.currentTime

Tags: iphone, sdk, uislider, avplayer

I am trying to set a UISlider's Value to a AVPlayer's Current Time.

I am trying to use this code `audioPlayer.currentTime = nowPlayingSlider.value;`

I am getting this error:
 `Setter method is needed to assign to object using property assignment syntax`

How do I get this to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how I handled this:

```
-(IBAction) timeScrubberChange:(id) sender{
CMTime t = CMTimeMake(self.nowPlayingTimeScrubber.value, 1);
self.nowPlayingCurrentTime.text = [self formatTimeCodeAsString: t.value];
self.nowPlayingDuration.text = [self formatTimeCodeAsString:(self.actualDuration - t.value)];
[self.avPlayer seekToTime:t];                                
}
```

Comment: I did something similar to this, but I ran into issues if a user scrobbled with the slider too fast.  Essentially, the player loads, the scrobble before playing, and then hit play.  It's like the avplayer ignores the seek and sets the currentTime back to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Sam, check this two methods:

-currentTime and -seekToTime:

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009530)

They are in AVPlayer class

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have it the other way round?

To set the slider to the current place in the sound it should be:

```
[nowPlayingSlider setValue:[audioPlayer currentTime]];
```

To skip in the audio according to a change of the slider:

```
[audioPlayer setCurrentTime:nowPlayingSlider.value];
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately setCurrentTime: does not exist

Comment: You might be right. But it works with AVAudioPlayer. (See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882753/avaudioplayer-currenttime-problem) question.)